# Car GameObject falling through the Terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been working on a project recently and there is a scene where there are mountains, forests and a car.

When the car moves on the terrain, the car penetrates through the terrain

I just want to know how to stop this from happening.

- On the Car there is Mesh Collider and RigidBody is attached
- On Terrain There is Mesh Collider with Convex to False.

---

```
public class Motor : MonoBehaviour {

public float moveSpeed = 5.0f;
public float drag = 0.5f;
public float terminalRoatationSpeed = 25.0f;
public Virtualjoystick moveJoystick;

private Rigidbody controller;
private Transform camTransform;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {


    controller = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    controller.maxAngularVelocity = terminalRoatationSpeed;
    controller.drag = drag;

    camTransform = Camera.main.transform;


}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {

    Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;

    dir.x = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    dir.z = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    if(dir.magnitude > 1)dir.Normalize();

    if(moveJoystick.InputDirection != Vector3.zero)
    {
        dir = moveJoystick.InputDirection;
    }



    // Rotate our Direction vector with Camera 
    Vector3 rotatedDir = camTransform.TransformDirection(dir);
    rotatedDir = new Vector3 (rotatedDir.x, 0, rotatedDir.z);
    rotatedDir = rotatedDir.normalized * dir.magnitude;

    controller.AddForce (rotatedDir * moveSpeed);


  }
}
```

Comment: Add more info to your question. How do you move the car...Code? Did you attach colliders to the car? Does this happen everytime or sometimes?

Comment: Add `RigidBody`s and make sure neither of them have the `IsTrigger` option set.

Comment: @TamásSzabó i Did that ...it Didn't Worked,Still the Car is Penetrating through the Terrain

Comment: As @Programmer said, how do you move your car? Snippets of your (I assume) CarController script could help us a lot. Just edit your question and include the code.

Comment: @TamásSzabó i Just Included the Code Which is Written on  the Car

Comment: @Murtuu You also mentioned what you have attached to the Terrain and Car game objects, but you didn't mention having a `RigidBody` on the Terrain. Do you, or do you not?

Comment: @TamásSzabó No There is No Rigidbody on the terrain

Comment: Put one there, and try it out

Comment: @TamásSzabó Tried Just Now Didn't Worked Same Problem

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this question before but can't find the other answer to mark this as a duplicate. You use [`WheelCollider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-WheelCollider.html) for cars.

**You need to attach [`WheelCollider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-WheelCollider.html) to all the wheels of your car.** By doing this your car will always be on top of the `Terrain Collider`.

[`WheelCollider.motorTorque`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WheelCollider-motorTorque.html) is used to move the car forward or backwards.

[`WheelCollider.brakeTorque`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WheelCollider-brakeTorque.html) is used to brake the car.

[`WheelCollider.steerAngle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WheelCollider-steerAngle.html) is used to steer the car.

There are many tutorials out there and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WheelColliderTutorial.html) is one  example directly from Unity's doc:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable]
public class AxleInfo {
    public WheelCollider leftWheel;
    public WheelCollider rightWheel;
    public bool motor;
    public bool steering;
}

public class SimpleCarController : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<AxleInfo> axleInfos; 
    public float maxMotorTorque;
    public float maxSteeringAngle;

    // finds the corresponding visual wheel
    // correctly applies the transform
    public void ApplyLocalPositionToVisuals(WheelCollider collider)
    {
        if (collider.transform.childCount == 0) {
            return;
        }

        Transform visualWheel = collider.transform.GetChild(0);

        Vector3 position;
        Quaternion rotation;
        collider.GetWorldPose(out position, out rotation);

        visualWheel.transform.position = position;
        visualWheel.transform.rotation = rotation;
    }

    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float motor = maxMotorTorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float steering = maxSteeringAngle * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        foreach (AxleInfo axleInfo in axleInfos) {
            if (axleInfo.steering) {
                axleInfo.leftWheel.steerAngle = steering;
                axleInfo.rightWheel.steerAngle = steering;
            }
            if (axleInfo.motor) {
                axleInfo.leftWheel.motorTorque = motor;
                axleInfo.rightWheel.motorTorque = motor;
            }
            ApplyLocalPositionToVisuals(axleInfo.leftWheel);
            ApplyLocalPositionToVisuals(axleInfo.rightWheel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok ThankUh for the answer i Will Try this Out

Comment: i attached the Wheel Colliders on the four Wheel and adjusted the radius according to the Size ...but when the collider's touch the terrain the car is bounced back in the air and rotating how to solve this

Comment: No this does solve the problem ....my Problem is when the car is moving on the terrain a if there is a slope on the terrain the car is going through the terrain and not climbing the slope and while the car is not touching the terrain while it's moving i need to make the car move on the terrain without going through it